# Can Caliburn.Micro be used for Visual Studio 2017 Extension Development?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, caliburn.micro, visual-studio-extensions

I have been trying to use Caliburn.Micro in my extension that I am developing for Visual Studio 2017. I created my own custom bootstrapper. I used the example listed here [Customer Bootstrapper](http://www.andyrace.com/2014/05/caliburn-micro-and-usercontrols.html). I kickstart my bootstrapper right after the extension's toolwindowpane is initialized. I have tried everything and it seems like I cannot get the Caliburn.Micro conventions to work. I am wondering if Caliburn.Micro can even work in an extension for Visual Studio!? The ToolWindowPane can host a WPF UserControl so I didn't think there would be an issue, but I cannot even get the ShellView to even see the ShellViewModel. Can someone let me know if Caliburn.Micro can work in this context???

Thanks!

Here is my BootStrapper:

```
  public class ClassBootStrapper : BootstrapperBase<IShellViewModel>
{
    private CompositionContainer container;

    private static BootstrapperBase bootstrapper;


    public static void Initialise()
    {
        if (null == bootstrapper)
        {
            bootstrapper = new ClassBootStrapper();
        }
    }

    private ClassBootStrapper() 
    {
       Initialize();
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies()
    {
        var baseAssemblies = new List<Assembly>(base.SelectAssemblies());


        var thisAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ClassBootStrapper));
        if (!baseAssemblies.Contains(thisAssembly))
        {
            baseAssemblies.Add(thisAssembly);
        }
        foreach (var assembly in baseAssemblies.ToList().Where(newAssembly => AssemblySource.Instance.Contains(newAssembly)))
        {
            baseAssemblies.Remove(assembly);
        }

        return baseAssemblies;
    }
}
```

Comment: i found the extension but it's said it works with VS2015 : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TheWinDev.CaliburnMicroWindows10Template

Comment: Could you post the code of your `ShellView` and `ShellViewModel`?

Comment: @MrTouya, What about this issue? Would you please post the "Q&A" under that extension site directly?

Comment: Hi, any update on this? I'm really struggling right now to integrate Caliburn.Micro in my Visual Studio Extension? I'm using VS 2019

Answer (score -2):

I test it in my side, it doesn't support the VS2017, you'd better to post the "Q & A" here:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TheWinDev.CaliburnMicroWindows10Template#overview

So the extension team could provide much more helpful information for this extension.